# ssh "Connection refused" on fresh Raspbian 11 lite?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, raspbian-lite, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I just installed Raspbian on an sd card using Rpi imager. I manually added the empty ssh file like I always do, booted up and ssh'ed into it. It worked great. Then I realised it was Raspbian 10 (old stable) while 11 is the current stable. Since I'm starting with a fresh installation I would like to start from the Raspbian 11. So I took out the sd card and then wrote Raspbian 11 on the sd card. I popped it in the rpi4 and booted it up. When I now try to ssh into it using the regular `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` I get

```
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi.local port 22: Connection refused
```

You normally get that while it is booting up, but it's been 20 minutes now and it's still giving the same response.

It's a Raspbian lite installation so I don't have another way of connecting to it.

Does anybody know what's going on here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: The policy around the `/boot/ssh` thing has changed; although the directly linked dupe doesn't have an answer, the dupe it includes does and I think the directly linked question does explain some pertinent details.